# Найти максимальное значение в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, математика, объекты, max

Есть динамический массив объектов с координатами, нужно получить объект с максимальным значением x:

```
var mass = [{ x: 34 }, { x: 12 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 348 }, { x: 15 }];
var maxObj = Math.max(mass[i].x);
```

Comment: Завести переменную "максимум", проитерировать массив и переписывать переменную, если в текущем итерируемом элементе значение больше, чем в переменной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

тут подойдет [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var maxObj=mass.reduce(function(prev,cur) {
    return cur.x>prev.x?cur:prev;
},{x:-Infinity});
```

в ES6 это будет чуть короче (и ИМХО не понятнее):

```
let maxObj=mass.reduce((prev,cur) => cur.x>prev.x?cur:prev,{x:-Infinity});
```

**Обновление**

var никуда не денется, и это не кофе. let отличается от var так:

```
var i=1;for (var i=0;i<10;i++){};console.log(i); //10
var i=1;for (let i=0;i<10;i++){};console.log(i); //1
```

Немного обновлю es6 вариант, чтобы не падал, если есть undefined значения:

```
const maxObj=mass.reduce((prev,cur) => cur?.x>prev.x?cur:prev,{x:-Infinity});
```

Comment: Классно, coffee делают нативынм. Вот только зачем заменять привычное почти для всех языков var на let...

Comment: Потрясающе! Именно то, что нужно. Спасибо)

Comment: Очень интересно. Совсем не знаю JS, но интересно, а чем такая запись (с .reduce()) лучше, чем тривиальный цикл по массиву?

Comment: Тем, что нету цикла по массиву)

Comment: @avp, тривиальный цикл по массиву - это как? 

array.forEach() ? - просто больше запись. 

Или просто перебор по длине? Иногда бывают массивы с дырками, задано первое и миллиардное значение.
 
Можно еще keys получить и их перебирать, тоже запись длиннее. 

Опять же анонимка с reduce может оказаться хинтом оптимизатору (сейчас или в будущем).

@panfilov, цикл есть, просто задан по-другому.

Comment: Массив с дырами, keys у элементов -- это, наверное, та структура данных, которую в Python называют `dictionary`?

Интересный в js подход, называть массивом такую коллекцию.

Comment: @avp, к dictionary ближе объект. Просто вот такая запись:

    a = [1,2,3];
    a[7] = 4;

приведет к

    [1, 2, 3, undefined × 4, 4]

a.length при этом будет равен 8.

Comment: @Etki, спасибо, как я понял, при переборе в цикле до length в js в общем случае программисту надо еще проверять, а существует ли i-й элемент.

Comment: @avp, я линуксоид, и для меня дыры в подобных структурах - нормальное явление, типа

    dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1 count=1 seek=1G #1G file занимает размер ссылки на него (зависит от файлухи) если подряд читать, то будет 1G нулей.

Comment: @eicto, я тоже. Файл на диске будет ровно занимать 1 блок (причем данные файла  в нем (тоже 0) -- 1 байт).

Только вот отличить настоящий 0 в файле от генерируемого при чтении пустого блока не очень просто. 

Поэтому сравнение нулевого байта с *undefined data* (видимо, есть такое понятие в js) выглядит несколько странно.

--

@eicto, комментарии у меня закончились, поэтому пишу просто тут. Я (как Вы уже поняли) прочел 2 Ваших крайних коммента о массивах в js, спасибо. 

Возможно, когда-нибудь и поизучаю js.

Comment: Ну, значения в массиве - это ссылки на данные, в файловой системе undefined затруднительно описать (программы этого ожидать точно не будут), а в js - легко. Т.е., я думаю, там так - нет ссылки в ячейке (скорее даже нет записи в словаре), значит - undefined. Почему в js это называется Array, не шибко важно, т.к. никакого другого похожего типа в js нет.

    >var a=[];a[10000]=1;
    > Object.keys(a)
    Array [ "10000" ]

Т.е. сам Array - это просто объект с числовыми ключами и известной длиной.

Comment: Вот еще пример: 

     > var b={1000:1,1001:2,length: 1002};var c=Array.prototype.splice.call(b,0)
     > Object.keys(c)
     Array [ "1000", "1001" ]
     > c
     Array [ , , , , , , , , , , , ещё 992… ]